# Volume per atom - Meaning

Tags: education, crystals, volume

The volume of a unit cell per atom is the volume of the cell in the case in which inside the cell there is only an atom?

Comment: A unit cell with only one atom? Volume of a unit cell "per atom"? Could you rewrite the question a bit to make it clearer? I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Steeven, on my book there is an exercise in which appear the formula $$V_{cell \space per \space atom}=\frac{V_{cell}}{number \space of \space atoms \space in \space the \space cell}$$

Comment: Aha, thank you for clearing it out. In that case, the *volume per atom* is just the volume which one atom takes up in the structure. Even though one atom doesn't actually fill this much, it still needs all this space to be in this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have here made the comment into an answer.*

The volume per atom is just the volume which one atom takes up in the structure. Even though one atom doesn't actually fill this much, it still needs all this space to be in this structure.

Comment: Hi @Steeven, is it correct to say that the volume per atom is the maximum volume that each atom can take up in the structure?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi What do you mean by maximum? Diving the unit cell volume with number of atoms, gives you the volume that the atom takes up right now. If the unit cell stretches or shrinks of other reasons, this value will of course also change.